# Help in understanding how to prove that :$lim_{x\to 0} sin(\frac{1}{x})\neq 0 $

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to break ice in understand the concept of proving the above problem. How do I achieve this mathematically.

My understanding is this. The value of $x$ in $f(x)=sin(\frac{1}{x}) $ at point $0$ DNE since it results in division by zero. Is this all for the proof?

Comment: No, that is the intuitive explanation. A proof would require epsilon-delta or possibly a theorem you learned in class.

Comment: I do know this was asked before here but couldn't find the link.

Comment: It is the behaviour of $\sin(1/x)$ near but not at $0$ that is the issue. For example, $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not defined at $x=0$, but $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ exists and is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it
is to find two sequences
$(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$
and
$(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$
such that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/a_n = 0$
and
$\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/b_n = 0$
and
$A = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(1/a_n)$
and
$B = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(1/b_n)$
both exist and
$A \ne B$.

Hint:
$\sin(\pi) \ne \sin(\pi/2)$.

Comment: Should be $A=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(a_n)$ and $A=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(b_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently to @marty's way:

- Assume it has a limit $c$ at $x=0$.
- Use the $\epsilon-\delta$ version and set $\epsilon=1/2$.
- For an sufficiently integer $n$, set $x_1=\frac{1}{(2n+1/2)\pi},~~x_2=\frac{1}{(2n-1/2)\pi}$.
- Try to show that in $0<|x|<\delta$ we could find $2=1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not sufficient. But one can simply note that $\forall \delta > 0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that $x=\frac{2}{\pi*(4N+1)}<\delta$. In particular, $y=\frac{2}{\pi*(4N+3)}<\delta$. So, $\sin(1/x) = \sin(\pi/2) = 1$ and $\sin(1/y) = \sin(3\pi/2) = -1$. Now, let $\epsilon \leq 1$ and we can easily establish a contradiction, since $\sin(1/x) - L < 1$ and $L - \sin(1/y) < 1$ imply $\sin(1/x) - \sin(1/y) < 1 + 1 = 2$. However, $\sin(1/x) - \sin(1/y) = \sin(\pi/2) - \sin(-\pi/2) = 1 - (-1) = 2$. So, we have a contradiction. Hence, the limit of $f(x) = \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ does not exist.

Comment: Does this answer help? Or are you looking for something other than an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof?